# Why is my scanner not reading PrintWriter data from a file?

Tags: java

I am attempting to store data in a file and then retrieve it for a class. For whatever reason, I can not figure out why this while loop near the end of my code is not being activated:

```
while ( inFile.hasNextInt() )
{
    token = inFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

As far as I am aware there are no mistakes within this actual method so here is the code as a whole, I have no been able to figure this out so any help would be awesome:

```
/**
 * Finding Fox Squirrel Population Averages
 *
 * @Miles Friedman
 * @12/11/19
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class AnimalPopulation
{
    public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
    {
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("stats.txt");
int trialsDone = 0;
        //determining # of trials
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Fox Squirrel Simulator");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("How many trials should be simulated?");
      System.out.println("Enter a value greater than 1000:");
      int trials = user.nextInt();
 if (trials <= 1000)
 {
      System.out.println("Enter a value greater than 1000:");
       trials = user.nextInt();
    }

     Random squirrelSpot = new Random();
     int spotNum = 0;

     while (trialsDone < trials)
         {
             int foxSquirrel = 0;
     for (int squirrelCounter = 0; foxSquirrel <= 0;)
     {
         spotNum = squirrelSpot.nextInt(10) + 1;
          if (spotNum > 9)
          {
          foxSquirrel ++;
          squirrelCounter++;
          trialsDone++;
         outFile.println(squirrelCounter);  
        }
          else
          squirrelCounter++;
        }
    }
int token = 0;
File reader = new File("stats.txt");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(reader);
    while ( inFile.hasNextInt() )
    {
        token = inFile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(token);
    }
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please sort out your indentation

Comment: Also, what does your `stats.txt` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
You need to close `PrintWriter` object first time for a file.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class AnimalPopulation
{
    public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
    {
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("stats.txt");
int trialsDone = 0;
        //determining # of trials
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Fox Squirrel Simulator");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("How many trials should be simulated?");
      System.out.println("Enter a value greater than 1000:");
      int trials = user.nextInt();
 if (trials <= 1000)
 {
      System.out.println("Enter a value greater than 1000:");
       trials = user.nextInt();
    }

     Random squirrelSpot = new Random();
     int spotNum = 0;

     while (trialsDone < trials)
         {
             int foxSquirrel = 0;
     for (int squirrelCounter = 0; foxSquirrel <= 0;)
     {
         spotNum = squirrelSpot.nextInt(10) + 1;
          if (spotNum > 9)
          {
          foxSquirrel ++;
          squirrelCounter++;
          trialsDone++;
         outFile.println(squirrelCounter);  
        }
          else
          squirrelCounter++;
        }
    }

     outFile.close(); // This close statement is require
int token = 0;
File reader = new File("stats.txt");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(reader);
    while ( inFile.hasNextInt() )
    {
        token = inFile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(token);
    }
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();    
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the Fox Squirrel Simulator

How many trials should be simulated?
Enter a value greater than 1000:
1001
4
25
26
6
5
4
11
4
7
5
4
6
8
10
12
9
12
2
10
1
8
11
13
2
16
3
2
3
16
5
6
24
9
4
6
3
1
17
11
5
7
1
1
1
12
4
6
2
14
5
9
5
11
3
13
2
2
9
4
4
4
17
3
3
7
8
4
20
10
14
3
27
3
31
40
3
14
7
41
2
4
11
13
2
1
17
16
10
14
4
3
12
1
23
3
22
14
10
3
2
3
19
18
10
8
5
4
3
6
14
5
9
10
12
10
13
2
10
12
8
23
5
5
4
2
7
10
10
2
25
13
18
6
1
10
8
17
4
1
14
1
2
16
13
21
37
6
23
11
3
4
9
13
4
11
2
4
6
7
1
3
14
13
7
9
8
7
3
3
12
24
4
6
7
22
15
1
9
2
4
2
16
14
23
19
2
13
1
2
17
2
1
24
18
1
3
13
18
2
25
2
5
1
11
6
48
12
1
1
7
16
10
1
3
24
7
2
5
3
13
32
33
6
4
1
5
4
28
29
12
10
3
7
5
1
16
4
31
6
1
18
6
12
37
1
22
1
1
11
1
49
15
2
1
3
5
1
4
12
7
2
2
6
6
12
11
19
9
10
12
6
15
6
15
14
5
35
1
4
4
10
30
3
3
14
15
4
2
2
5
30
4
5
9
2
18
1
4
7
6
7
3
2
7
19
3
7
6
14
3
7
7
15
2
1
1
8
11
41
9
5
6
22
5
3
2
15
19
2
4
3
46
14
4
1
2
26
3
1
20
28
7
3
13
29
4
9
13
19
20
2
10
11
12
1
2
3
12
1
3
8
3
14
24
3
11
2
1
3
9
2
19
2
1
6
1
10
4
2
6
1
5
2
4
1
12
13
1
12
7
2
11
4
11
6
1
12
2
13
4
9
5
4
34
20
6
3
8
18
10
8
4
10
3
18
13
3
23
22
3
27
1
11
17
8
17
27
54
10
10
15
22
5
20
3
10
51
3
9
19
7
2
3
3
1
7
24
2
7
17
4
9
19
5
1
1
7
10
3
1
1
9
3
2
1
18
16
3
2
8
5
4
4
7
7
12
5
1
5
7
24
9
8
22
1
4
1
2
1
6
7
9
1
14
15
8
25
15
18
9
31
11
2
1
4
1
3
4
4
7
2
2
8
3
4
12
8
8
12
19
14
7
9
4
10
28
7
12
20
16
4
6
23
2
28
1
7
6
6
12
15
13
15
3
5
16
3
7
5
6
7
2
21
8
22
5
12
1
10
8
1
6
2
10
7
21
20
8
12
6
29
2
3
3
6
6
1
17
10
3
1
38
3
4
11
3
4
1
13
25
12
25
2
7
9
24
15
8
4
21
5
4
11
14
6
15
3
7
6
2
2
29
5
7
26
2
25
35
9
7
11
8
8
9
3
1
8
1
6
7
11
7
9
11
16
4
2
2
1
3
6
6
25
6
1
1
4
12
2
31
8
6
5
1
3
6
12
3
16
24
16
3
7
3
12
1
6
40
8
1
4
15
2
1
7
2
9
43
2
3
7
6
6
23
5
7
19
2
13
3
20
2
2
5
6
21
21
13
1
3
3
14
3
16
1
17
17
3
3
6
1
24
5
6
5
4
1
3
7
4
9
6
4
27
3
5
36
24
1
5
2
12
16
1
1
12
4
22
2
5
8
5
4
17
2
3
1
3
5
3
2
2
1
15
24
19
5
4
24
2
24
1
15
6
2
1
17
18
4
16
6
2
31
7
18
17
5
12
24
3
1
4
2
15
5
21
19
11
10
7
1
6
8
1
39
5
11
1
15
1
5
1
22
6
36
31
59
28
9
8
9
3
8
9
12
14
4
2
3
11
1
3
13
32
9
31
8
10
17
3
10
15
5
15
21
3
2
3
5
20
5
2
15
1
9
15
5
1
4
2
1
13
5
1
2
4
14
5
7
9
5
8
1
2
10
10
2
1
3
1
32
11
16
13
10
8
16
22
52
24
12
1
1
7
18
6
20
17
17
5
1
6
21
2
7
3
36
12
7
9
8
3
10
4
9
46
1
1
3
3
21
1
13
14
1
31
12
16
3
13
1
23
2
12
4
14
4
17
20
6
3
5
3
3
16
4
14
2
3
22
11
12
20
5
9
2
33
15
9
1
10
5
1
9
24
61
20
3
6
3
4
4
2
8
7
7
3
7
1
16
16
8
2
6
17
7
9
1
5
1
2
16
8
18
3
3
10
8
30
2
12
1
14
2
4
7
4
51
6
2
25
```